# Route present, but can't DESTROY object, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, actioncontroller

I am unable to destroy an object with a valid route. Browser returns `No route matches [POST] "/blog/topics/3/posts/1"`. However I can perform all other actions on the same resource. How should my controller, template look given I can create and destroy the object from the console?

Save time-these routes don't work either under my current config:

- link_to([@topic, @post]) returns http://localhost:3000/blog/topics/3/1/posts/1.
- link_to([@topic]) returns http://localhost:3000/blog/topics/3/posts/1. #Still does not delete

**Here is my controller:**

```
class Blog::PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :fetch_topic, except: [:index]
  before_filter :fetch_post, except: [:create, :new]

  #stuff that works.
  ..
  ..
  ..

  def destroy
   @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to blog_topic_posts_url, notice: 'Post deleted.'}
    end
       #DOES NOT work: redirect_to root_url([:blog, @topic, @post]), notice: 'Post deleted.'
  end

  private  
   def fetch_post
    @post =  @topic.posts.find(params[:id]) 
   end

   def fetch_topic
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
   end
```

**Here is my template:**

```
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', blog_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), method: :destroy, confirm: 'You Sure About This?' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `method: :delete`.

Comment: I got my VERB action confused, lazy of me.

Answer (score 3):

I think your link_to might be wrong. Looking on the [RoR API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) the link_to options should be like `:method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?"`.

Also, your `:fetch_post` filter doesn't run for action `destroy`, so you won't have `@post` or `@topic` for that matter, because `:fetch_topic` doesn't get called either.

Comment: It's annoying that it's `POST` to `create`,  `PUT` to `update`, and `DELETE` to `destroy`. REST semantics and Rails semantics are different.

Comment: @MrDanA I am using the `except` filter, which runs my filter on all actions except those explicitly stated. @tadman seriously. I am able to CRUD posts but now I get a strange error I will now investigate.

Comment: This confuses many people. The link is `:method => :delete`, but the controller method is `destroy`. Good answer.

Comment: @rhodee Oh my apologies. For some reason I read it as :only and not :except.